# import mysql.connector, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: mysql-python, mysql-connector, database-connectivity

I am encountering an issue with a `ModuleNotFoundError` when trying to import the mysql.connector module in my Python script. I have already installed the module using `pip install mysql-connector-python`, but I still can't seem to resolve the error.

1.Checked Python version: 3.11.1

2.Executed pip show mysql-connector-python:

> Name: mysql-connector-python
>
> Version: 8.3.0
>
> Summary: MySQL driver written in Python.

3.Checked virtual environment activation:

> Virtual environment is activated.

4.Reinstalled MySQL Connector:

```
pip uninstall mysql-connector-python  
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: What is your OS? can you add output from `pip --version` and `python --version`, can you place how are you staring script? I did `pip install mysql-connector-python` and `python3 -c 'import mysql.connector'` on clean system and it works fine

Comment: OS: Windows, pip version : pip 23.3.2, python version : Python 3.11.1.                           It didn't work.

Comment: Do you have other python version in the system? try using `python3 -m pip install mysql-connector-python` to install it, then again it `python3 -c 'import mysql.connector'`

Comment: Yes, another Python version was there. I uninstalled the previous versions and installed the latest Python version. Then, I used `pip install mysql-connector-python`, and it worked without any issues.